# No me deja seleccionar los checks asociados al radio 1, sin embargo cuando no hay nada seleccionado si que me deja

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
  <script>
          function disable()
          {
            if (document.getElementById("R1").checked)
              {
              document.getElementById("cami").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("pack").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("mark").disabled=true;

              document.getElementById("abog").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("deli").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("grui").disabled=true;
              }
            else
              {
              document.getElementById("cami").disabled=false;
              document.getElementById("pack").disabled=false;
              document.getElementById("mark").disabled=false;

              document.getElementById("abog").disabled=false;
              document.getElementById("deli").disabled=false;
              document.getElementById("grui").disabled=false;
              }


           if (document.getElementById("R2").checked)
              {
              document.getElementById("cami").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("pack").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("mark").disabled=true;

              document.getElementById("font").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("elec").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("tele").disabled=true;
              }

            if (document.getElementById("R3").checked)
            {
              document.getElementById("font").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("elec").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("tele").disabled=true;

              document.getElementById("abog").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("deli").disabled=true;
              document.getElementById("grui").disabled=true;
            }

          }
</script>
</head>
<html>  
<form name="categoria">
  <fieldset>
  <legend><h1>Selecciona tu especialidad</h1></legend>
    <input type="radio" name="Especialidad" value="Especialidad1" id="R1" onChange="disable()"/>Especialidad 1 
    <input type="radio" name="Especialidad" value="Especialidad2" id="R2" onClick="disable()"/>Especialidad 2 
    <input type="radio" name="Especialidad" value="Especialidad3" id="R3" onClick="disable()"/>Especialidad 3<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="fontanero" id="font" /> Fontanero

<input type="checkbox" name="electricista" id="elec"/> Electricista

<input type="checkbox" name="teleco" id="tele"/>Teleco<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="abogado" id="abog"/> Abogado

<input type="checkbox" name="delineante" id="deli"/>Delineante

<input type="checkbox" name="gruista" id="grui"/>Gruista<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="camionero" id="cami"/> Camionero

<input type="checkbox" name="packaging" id="pack"/>Packaging

<input type="checkbox" name="marketing" id="mark"/>Repartidores

  </fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero es que tienes un `onChange` en el `radiobutton1` en vez de `onClick` pero el problema es cómo estás gestionando los `if`. Piensa en cuál sería un ciclo normal:

1. El usuario hace click en el `radiobutton2`, por ejemplo. Se deshabilitan las filas 1 y 3 y no hay problema.
2. Ahora el usuario hace click en el `radiobutton1`. Entra en el primer `if` y deshabilita las filas 2 y 3 (la 1 ya estaba deshabilitada) por lo que no permite seleccionar ningún `check` (no estás habilitando los check de la fila 1 en ningún momento)
3. Si ahora pulsaran el `radiobutton3` entraría en el `else` del primer `if` y habilitaría las filas 2 y 3 y luego entraría en el último `if` y deshabilitaría la fila 2.

Lo mejor es que habilites y deshabilites en cada condición y además que utilices `else if` para ahorrarte comparaciones innecesarias.

```js
function disable(){
  if (document.getElementById("R1").checked){
    document.getElementById("cami").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("pack").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("mark").disabled=true;

    document.getElementById("abog").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("deli").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("grui").disabled=true;
              
    document.getElementById("font").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("elec").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("tele").disabled=false;
 }
else if (document.getElementById("R2").checked){
    document.getElementById("cami").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("pack").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("mark").disabled=true;

    document.getElementById("font").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("elec").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("tele").disabled=true;
              
    document.getElementById("abog").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("deli").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("grui").disabled=false;
}
else{
    document.getElementById("font").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("elec").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("tele").disabled=true;

    document.getElementById("abog").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("deli").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("grui").disabled=true;
              
    document.getElementById("cami").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("pack").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("mark").disabled=false;
  }

}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<html>  
<form name="categoria">
  <fieldset>
  <legend><h1>Selecciona tu especialidad</h1></legend>
    <input type="radio" name="Especialidad" value="Especialidad1" id="R1" onClick="disable()"/>Especialidad 1 
    <input type="radio" name="Especialidad" value="Especialidad2" id="R2" onClick="disable()"/>Especialidad 2 
    <input type="radio" name="Especialidad" value="Especialidad3" id="R3" onClick="disable()"/>Especialidad 3<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="fontanero" id="font" /> Fontanero

<input type="checkbox" name="electricista" id="elec"/> Electricista

<input type="checkbox" name="teleco" id="tele"/>Teleco<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="abogado" id="abog"/> Abogado

<input type="checkbox" name="delineante" id="deli"/>Delineante

<input type="checkbox" name="gruista" id="grui"/>Gruista<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="camionero" id="cami"/> Camionero

<input type="checkbox" name="packaging" id="pack"/>Packaging

<input type="checkbox" name="marketing" id="mark"/>Repartidores

  </fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```